# Append new elements in form and post it values in PHP and save it in database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Basically what I'm trying to do is to DYNAMICALLY APPEND elements in a form and save their values to MySQL using PHP so far I've started adding but I don't know how to post their values.. Here is what I've done so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script>
<script> 
 $('document').ready(function(){ 


 $('#save').live('click',function(e){ 
   /*
   this should be the function that gets and post all elements in php 
   */  
   //maybe the use of $.post or .load() or ajax

}); 

$('#add').click(function(){
$("<br><input type='text' class='do'name='do'>").appendTo('form');

});

}); 

 </script></head>
<body>
<form> //this was the form that im appending
<input type='text' class='do' name="do"><br> 
<input type='text' class='do' name="do"><br> 
<input type='text' class='do' name="do"><br> 

</form>

<input type='button' id='add' value='[+]'>
<input type='button' id='save' value='go2'><br>


<div id='res'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and i want to save all values in database using php so just for example here is the php

```
<?php
//
mysql_query("INSERT <blablabla HERE>");

?>
```

please help me with this stuff... thanks..

Comment: So you need the 'blablabla" part or what?

Comment: are you looking for examples on how to use jquery ajax?

Comment: the "blabla" part is  the POSTED values of the DYNAMICALLY ADDED elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple snippet of code can answer this for you:

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="btn_submit">
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#btn_submit").mousedown(function() {
    $("form").append("<input name='foo' value='bar'>");
});
```

PHP:

```
$myValue = $_POST["foo"];

mysql_query("insert into myTable (foo), ($myValue)");
```

Comment: that looks promising...but how could i post the value in php then save it afterwards??? can it be done by ajax or something??

Answer (score 0):

On every add click, you need to make an ajax call to a page, where (the ajax-called page) the mysql-insert would be performed.

Consider using [Jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to append the form while saving the information to a database, why not just pull the list from the database (Holding all significant values), then reload using AJAX after the 'appending', which will programmatically be just adding the value to the end of the database. Voila! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the jquery form plugin .http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Here form submitted using ajax , so it will not refresh the form  and also you will get all the values posted as what php does

Comment: i know those but what im trying to do is post the values of elements that are appended dynamically..

Comment: There are plenty of events and options in that plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object

Answer (score 0):

change name of the form text boxes **'do'** to **do[]**

```
 $('#save').live('click',function(e){ 
   /*
   this should be the function that gets and post all elements in php 
   */  
   //maybe the use of $.post or .load() or ajax

}); 

$('#add').click(function(){
$("<br><input type='text' class='do' name='do[]'>").appendTo('form');

});



<form> //this was the form that im appending
**<input type='text' class='do' name="do[]"><br> 
<input type='text' class='do' name="do[]"><br> 
<input type='text' class='do' name="do[]"><br>** 

</form>

<input type='button' id='add' value='[+]'>
<input type='button' id='save' value='go2'><br>
```